# Openlink Virtuoso upgrade 6.x to 7.x on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, upgrade, openlink-virtuoso

I have installed Openlink Virtuoso using the ubuntu packages following the instructions in http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSUbuntuNotes .

I have Ubuntu 16.04, and this process installed virtuoso version 06.01.3127, which is rather old.

So, I decided to upgrade version 6.x to 7.x downloading the prebuilt binaries for GNU/Linux as given in http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSDownload#Pre-built%20binaries following the instructions in http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/UpgradingToVOS610#Upgrading%20from%20Release%206.x%20to%20Release%207.x .

In the above instructions it is not clear to me what should I do for steps 3, 4, and 5.

> 3. Start a fresh terminal session, and install the newer v7.x binary components, either atop or after removing the older v6.x binary
>      components.
> 4. Set the environment with the new Virtuoso 7.x script, and start the instance with the new Virtuoso 7.x binary, which will automatically
>      upgrade the v6.x to the new v7.x database structure in its original
>      row wise storage format.
> 5. Virtuoso 7 supports Column wise storage providing 3 times better data compression over row wise storage, enabling 3 times the data to
>      be stored in the same memory and disk space. Thus conversion of
>      relevant existing tables to column wise storage should be considered,
>      especially for Business Intelligence type work loads and RDF Data
>      Storage, with the document How to convert from Row Store to Column
>      Store Table providing an example on how this can be done for the
>      RDF_QUAD table used for RDF Data storage.

For 3 I replaced the binaries of the old installation with the newly downloaded binaries, for me that meant copying binaries in /usr/bin directory.

For 4 I updated the virtuoso.ini file given the sample provided when downloaded the prebuilt binaries.

For 5 I did nothing since I did not had any data in the initial virtuoso installation.

The virtuoso version is now 07.20.3229 in localhost:8890.

Also, I checked the version using the  virtuoso-t -? command and via an appropriate SPARQL query as in http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtCheckSvrVersionViaSparql .

Therefore, the actions I made were correct and the upgrade is completed?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have done everything correctly...  Have you observed some problem, that brought you to ask this question?

That said -- given that you had loaded no data to the v6 `virtuoso.db` file, I would suggest that you **delete** this file, and let Virtuoso v7 create a fresh one upon next launch -- as this will automatically enable several performance enhancements that are defaults for new v7 DB files (such as the column-wise storage mentioned in the doc you quoted), which must be manually applied to v6 DB files opened by v7 engines (as described in the step #5 you skipped).

I also suggest that you download [updated v7.2-specific VAD archives](http://download3.openlinksw.com/index.html?prefix=uda/vad-vos-packages/7.2/), to replace the v6-specific builds in your existing `/vads/` directory, whether you plan to install these or not, as you may change your mind later, and updating now will save headache later.